# WCF on Azure with STS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure, wif

I had hosted WCF on Azure and would like to redirect any request to STS first if not authenticated.

So, if user typed following : `http://....../mywcfservice.svc`, in the address bar, it should first redirect to STS login page if not authenticated.

I had already implemented same in WebApplication, but when implemented the same configuration in WCf, it doesn't redirects to sts login but it just shows - "Access is denied"

Why is it not redirecting it to STS Login page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF does not use redirect - the same as your WCF clients are not browser clients. You need to use WS-Trust to do STS-based authentication in WCF. (see ws2007FederationHttpBinding in WCF docs).

Comment: Yes. @anil: You should look up and learn the terms "Active Federation" and "Passive Federation". Since web sites run in browsers, you can use some browser tricks to make it all *passive* so it *just works*, but with web services, you can't give the "user" (an application) a dynamic experience - it must be predictable. As such, you must describe the specifications to the "user" (app) so it is *actively* involved in the authentication experience.

Comment: @leastprivilege, could you please let me know how to use WS-Trust to do STS based authentication in WCF?

Comment: As I said - using the ws2007FederationHttpBinding binding. This is well documented.